# Xcode Instrument Measure Average CPU Load

Tags: instruments, xcode-instruments

I am using Xcode Instrument Tool to Measure My App's CPU Usage. Is there a way to find out the average CPU usage in a certain period of time? I have tried to export the .trace file to xml format and still couldn't find out.

[image]